# threading.get_ident() returns same ID between different threads when running pytest

Tags: python, multithreading

I have created a small test case using pytest to demonstrate the issue:

```py
from threading import Thread, get_ident

def test_threading():
    threads = []
    ids = []

    def append_id():
        # time.sleep(1)
        ids.append(get_ident())

    for _ in range(5):
        thread = Thread(target=append_id)
        threads.append(thread)
        thread.start()

    for thread in threads:
        thread.join()

    assert len(set(ids)) == 5
```

The test is failing because `get_ident` returns the same ID for different threads. But when I add `time.sleep(1)` in each thread, the test passes.
I'm not sure I understand why.

I'm using Python 3.9.0 and Pytest 7.1.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.get_ident) of `get_ident`:

> Return the ‘thread identifier’ of the current thread. This is a nonzero integer. Its value has no direct meaning; it is intended as a magic cookie to be used e.g. to index a dictionary of thread-specific data. Thread identifiers may be recycled when a thread exits and another thread is created.

Since your threads are running too quickly (without the `time.sleep(1)`), the ids are being recycled.

You can provide a `name` to each thread. This [name](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.name) does not have to be unique, but you can use it in your test (or in your application, if you need something that is unique in a context):

```py
from threading import Thread, get_ident, current_thread

def test_threading():
    threads = []
    names = []
    ids = []

    def append_id():
        # time.sleep(1)
        ids.append(get_ident())
        names.append(current_thread().name)

    for i in range(5):
        thread = Thread(target=append_id, name=f'Thread {i}')
        threads.append(thread)
        thread.start()

    for thread in threads:
        thread.join()

    assert len(set(names)) == 5
    print(f'Names: {names}')
    print(f'Ids: {set(ids)}')
```

Comment: Thank you, is it possible to obtain a non-recycled id for each thread? I want to differentiate between the threads

Comment: As @nunDucor suggests, you can uncomment the `time.sleep(1)`.  That will most likely cause all threads to exist at the same time.

Comment: @KfirCohen, I extended the answer to include using `name`. It is not a GUID, but it may work in the context of your application.